# Dictionary in Python not working correctly from csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a `csv` file that contains wifi information about different companies in my area.  The name of the telco that they get their wifi from is located in one column.  I need to create a dictionary in python with the telco name as the key and the number of occurrences that it occurs in the column as the value.

I am using the `.read().splitlines()` method to read in the `csv`, but I'm having a lot of trouble actually breaking up the data because some of the cells contain commas.

***Code:***

```
    def printer(csvreadsplit):  #prints each line of a csv that has been read and split
    for line in csvreadsplit:
        print line


file_new = open("/Users/marknovice/Downloads/Updated_Cafe.csv", "r")

lines1 = file_new.read().splitlines()

printer(lines1)

writer1 = open("Cafe_Data.csv", "w+")

def telcoappeareances(filecsv):
    telconumber = {}
    for line in filecsv:
        if "Singtel" or "SingTel" in line:
            if "Singtel" or "SingTel" not in telconumber.keys():
                telconumber["SingTel"] = 1
            else:
                telconumber["SingTel"] += 1
        if "Starhub" or "StarHub" in line:
            if "Starhub" or "StarHub" not in telconumber.keys():
                telconumber["StarHub"] = 1
            else:
                telconumber["StarHub"] += 1
        if "Viewqwest" or "ViewQwest" in line:
            if "Viewqwest" or "ViewQwest" not in telconumber.keys():
                telconumber["ViewQwest"] = 1
            else:
                telconumber["ViewQwest"] += 1
        if "M1" in line:
            if ["M1"] not in telconumber.keys():
                telconumber["M1"] = 1
            else:
                telconumber["M1"] += 1
        if "MyRepublic" or "Myrepublic" in line:
            if "MyRepublic" or "Myrepublic" not in telconumber.keys():
                telconumber["MyRepublic"] = 1
            else:
                telconumber["MyRepublic"] += 1
    print telconumber.keys()
    print telconumber.values()

telcoappeareances(lines1)
```

***Results:***

```
['MyRepublic', 'StarHub', 'ViewQwest', 'M1', 'SingTel']
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: JFYI, python comes with a [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Much obliged, I started researching that and have been using this since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use csv module instead so you will be able to declare comma as delimiter:

```
import csv

with open("/Users/marknovice/Downloads/Updated_Cafe.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=str(u','), quotechar=str(u'"'))
```

Then you can iterate over your reader to get your comma separated values